# Is it possible to arrange divs to form a horizontal nav menu?

Tags: html, css

I've made a horizontal nav menu using HTML and css. I've used display:inline in li. But I'm facing a problem here. I'm also using div tag within the li tag. Therefore, there is improper output. I'm getting a vertical menu. But it is important to use div tag. Is there any other way to make a horizontal nav menu in which div tags can be used in between. This is a small example what i want to do.

```
<ul class="somethingabcd">
    <li class="somethingdef">
        anythingabcd
    </li>
    <li class="somethingdef>
        <div class="container show" id="page-1">
            <p><a class="pageload-link" href="#page-2">Show Page Loader</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="page-2">
            <section>
                <h2>This is an example for a new page.</h2>
                <p><a class="pageload-link" href="#page-1">Go back</a></p>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div id="loader" class="pageload-overlay" data-opening="M20,15 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z;M0,0 80,0 50,30 20,45 Z;M0,0 80,0 60,45 0,60 Z;M0,0 80,0 80,60 0,60 Z" data-closing="M0,0 80,0 60,45 0,60 Z;M0,0 80,0 50,30 20,45 Z;M20,15 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z;M30,30 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <path d="M30,30 50,30 50,30 30,30 Z"/>
                </svg>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In CSS file I've given `li {display:inline}`. But I'm not getting a horizontal nav menu. Does anyone can figure out the solution to make this right?

Comment: Provide a proper title so that others can search and benefit.

Comment: add your CSS to the question

Comment: Please use a title that describes the problem. We already know that you need help, otherwise you wouldn't be asking a question here. Imagine everybody would use "need help with xyz" as title. It would be impossible to find anything.

Comment: Please consider upvoting material that appears to be helpful, even if the problem is abandoned (in relation to the answer below, which only currently has my upvote). Also, note that if you need to request for other users to connect via screen-sharing tools, it means you have not described the problem in sufficient detail _in the question_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) instead of display: inline;  try display: inline-block;

2) Instead of trying to make a UL horizontal, why not use `<div>` tags instead? Set the `<div>`s to display: inline-block, and you should be able to get the horizontal list you're describing.

```
<div class="container">
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <h2>This is heading ?</h2>
    <p><a href="?">This is link ?</a></p>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <h2>This is heading ?</h2>
    <p><a href="?">This is link ?</a></p>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <h2>This is heading ?</h2>
    <p><a href="?">This is link ?</a></p>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <h2>This is heading ?</h2>
    <p><a href="?">This is link ?</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

I would use this format, not a UL

**EDITED**

You need to reorganize your `<div class="saurav100">`

I recommend the following structure:

```
<div class="saurav100">
  <span>Tech &nbsp;Store</span>
  <span><a class="pageload-link" href="#page-2">Login</a></span>
</div>
```

Then just remove the styling from the 'login' link with:

```
link {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: @ιηςπεδιδιεζαυπαυ: seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/d8gq3j3e/. Please provide more information about what "doesn't work".

Comment: Bro, can you please come on teamviewer? I wont be able to explain unless you exactly see my problem. Please I request you. I'm stuck in this problem since many days, please help me @FelixKling !